# Duplicate entries in the list

Tags: python-3.x

Having to enter 8 unique entries, logic should detect if any entry is duplicate otherwise continue until all 8 entries are entered.

I've played around with the For loop but it seems to not give me desired output, i want to go back to last entry if duplicate entry is scanned instead it will give a message "Duplicate SCAN, please rescan" but also the counter moves on.

sorry, i'm new to this i thought i've included code. Hoping it goes through this time.

```
x=1
mac_list = []
while (x <=8):
    MAC1 = input("SCAN MAC"+str(x)+":")

for place in mac_list:

    print (mac_list)
    if place==MAC1:
        print ("place"+place)
        print ("Duplicate SCAN, please rescan")
else:
    mac_list.append(MAC1)           
    x+=1
```

Comment: Could you include a code example of what you have already tried including the line that gives the message you've included.

Comment: Hello.  You should post what you have already tried, you'll get better feedback!  It is pretty straightforward to see if you have already seen an entry before by using the `in` command to test for membership.  So you should probably do something like test to see if the value is already in your list or set, then use logic to either pop the error or add it.

Answer (score 1):

Python's `in` comparison should do what you need:

```py
values = []

while True:
    value = input('Input value: ')

    if value in values:
        print('Duplicate, please try again')

    else:
        values.append(value)

    if len(values) > 7:
        break

print(values)
```

Comment: There is no `raw_input` in Python 3.x.

Answer (score 0):

Would something like this not work?

Sets can only hold unique elements and thus remove any duplicates by default - that should solve a lot of your worries. This should work better for larger datasets over elementwise comparison.

```
entries = set()

while len(entries)<8:
    entries = entries ^ set([input("You do not have enough unique items yet, add another")])
```

To detect a change you can have an old list and a new one:

```
entries = set()
new=set()


while True:

    latest = input("You do not have enough unique items yet, add another")
    new = entries ^ set([latest])
    if len(new) == len(entries):
        print("you entered a duplicate:",latest, " Please rescan")
    else:
        entries = new
        if len(entries) == 8 : break
```

Answer (score 0):

Store the entries in a set, check if the set has fewer than 8 elements. If it does not, break the loop.

```
entries = set()
counter = 0

while len(entries) < 8:
    counter += 1
    entries.add(input("Enter an item: "))
```